# How do you remove a custom word from SlideIT?

Tags: dictionary

How do you remove a custom word from SlideIT?

(hint: the `User dictionary` list in `Language & keyboard settings`, is, quite obviously, not the answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=kkUGRzwt2I4) video.

> To remove a word press on **-** sign.